# Show hide marker using circle points openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

How to show hide markers (P icon) using circle points (something like point1.distanceTo(point2))

need to show markers If markers comes inside the circle another hide it (currently changing circle radius through slider)

```js
// we change this on input change
var radius = 10;
  longitude = 400000;
  latitude = 300000;


var styleFunction = function() {
  return new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: radius,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: [51, 51, 51],
        width: 2
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [51, 51, 51, .3]
      })
    })
  });
};

var update = function(value) {
 // $('#range').val() = value;
  radius = value;
  vectorLayer.setStyle(styleFunction);
 // $('#range').val(value)
 // document.getElementById('range').value=value;
}

var feature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([longitude, latitude]));
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [feature]
  }),
  style: styleFunction
});
 var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
   source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
     url: 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.geography-class.json',
     crossOrigin: ''
   })
 });

// icon marker start here

var iconFeature5 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([longitude, latitude]),
  name: 'Missing Person',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500
});

var vectorSource5 = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [iconFeature5]
});

var vectorLayer5 = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource5
});

var iconStyle5 = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    
    src: 'https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/41094/2833021/7279fac0-cfcb-11e3-9789-24436486a8b1.png'
  }))
});
iconFeature5.setStyle(iconStyle5);

// 2nd marker

  longitude1 = 100000;
  latitude1 = 100000;
var iconFeature1 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([longitude1, latitude1]),
  name: 'Missing Person',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500
});

var vectorSource1 = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [iconFeature1]
});

var vectorLayer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource1
});

iconFeature1.setStyle(iconStyle5);



var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [rasterLayer,vectorLayer,vectorLayer5,vectorLayer1],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [400000, 400000],
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.input {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.16.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div class="input">
  <input type="range" id="range" min="10" max="50" onchange="update(this.value)">
  <input type="text" id="range" value="10">
</div>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a Point and not an actual circle geometry, as you said distanceTo is probably the solution for this, you have to add it in your update function :

```
var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);

var update = function(value) {
 // $('#range').val() = value;
  radius = value;
  vectorLayer.setStyle(styleFunction);
  if(wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(),iconFeature5.getGeometry().getCoordinates())<=radius){
      vectorLayer5.setVisible(true);
  }
  else{
      vectorLayer5.setVisible(false);
  }
  if(wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(),iconFeature1.getGeometry().getCoordinates())<=radius){
      vectorLayer1.setVisible(true);
  }
  else{
      vectorLayer1.setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: console.log('get' + iconFeature5.getGeometry()); Results = get[object Object]

Comment: It does return a point object. But if what you want is coordinates then you can use feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()

Comment: Ya thanks Its giving points.. but don't know how to show hide from the circle radius.. cn u plz help me in this logic.. Actual requirement is slider with 1 miles to 5 miles range. and show and hide with that radius..

Comment: I'd like to know how you define the function distanceTo() ?

Comment: I used same as u
var point1 = iconFeature5.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
   var point2 = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
if(point1.distanceTo(point2)<=radius){
      vectorLayer5.setVisible(true);
  }

Comment: Its working fine with opelayers 2 In openlayres 3 giving error distanceTo is not a function \

Comment: Need to change radius in miles first

Comment: I thought that you have already coded a function distanceTo. There is no such function in ol3 however there is haversineDistance which does pretty much the same

Comment: Can you plz tell how to use that haversineDistance ol3 function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118813/discussion-between-hicham-zouarhi-and-sagar).